# Speaker Diarization always returns zero with long audios in C#

Tags: c#, google-speech-api

I am currently working with the google cloud speech to Text SDK for c#. The nuget package i'm using is Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1. I am trying to benefit from speech diarization for longer videos but it always return 0 in the speaker tag for all the words no matter how many speakers are there in the audio. below is my code

```
var longOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(new RecognitionConfig()
               {
                   Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                   DiarizationSpeakerCount = 2,
                   EnableSpeakerDiarization = true,
                   SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                   LanguageCode = "en",
               }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile("testRecording.wav"));

               longOperation = longOperation.PollUntilCompleted();
               var response = longOperation.Result;
               Console.WriteLine("Response received successfully.");

               foreach (var result in response.Results)
               {
                   foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                   {
                       foreach (var word in alternative.Words)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine($"{word.Word}: {word.SpeakerTag}");
                       }
                   }
               }
```